# How to send Date object as parameter in JAVA

Tags: java, class, date

I have a Booking Class which has a Date variable in it.

Basically, I want to do add a new variable to ArrayList called "bookings". It works for SSN ,but Date type does not pass in this way. Why is it and what should I do to fix this situation?

Code in my "main"

```
bookings.add(new Booking(new Date(18,11,2020), SSN));
```

Here is Booking Class

```
public class Booking {
    
    private Date bookingDate;
    private int SSN;
    
    public Booking(Date bookingDate, int SSN) { // constructor
       this.bookingDate=bookingDate;
       this.SSN=SSN;
    }
}
```

Comment: Spoiler alert: `new Date(18,11,2020)` returns `Wed Jun 11 00:00:00 EDT 1924`

Comment: Yes it is ,but why :))?

Comment: In the description of Date class it says , Date constructor is Date(dd,mm,yyyy)

Comment: So, do you know how to fix it :)

Comment: I think it might have something to do with the fact that the constructor Date(int, int, int) is deprecated

Comment: What do you mean by "but Date type does not pass in this way"? Is there an error?

Comment: Not an error ,but it gives Wed Jun 11 00:00:00 EDT 1924 as output instead of the one that i sent

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Date`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `LocalDate` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). And even if you insisted on `Date`, stay far away from the three-arg constructor that has been deprecated for almost 25 years because it works unreliably across time zones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not using the `Date` constructor properly.

The constructor for Date is in your case:

```
new Date(int year, int month, int date);
```

You should be using:

```
Date date = new Date(120, 11, 18);
```

Which returns

```
Fri Dec 18 00:00:00 EST 2020
```

**ALSO**: Take note that the `year` is actually the year - 1900 (e.g, the number of years from 1900).

It is now recommended to use use `Calendar.set(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min)` or `GregorianCalendar(year + 1900, month, date, hrs, min)`.

Comment: Just my opinion: helping to use a class and a constructor that people shouldn’t use at all is not really helpful. The `Date` class is poorly and confusingly designed and long outdated, and fact, the constructor has been deprecated for a reason since Java 1.1, Fabruary 1997.

Comment: Thank you for sharing your experience.I will pass to this way next time.

Answer (score 1):

### java.time

> … and what should I do to fix this situation?

I very strongly recommend that you’re using java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your dates. The `LocalDate` class from java.time represents a date without time of day. It’s got a couple of well-working factory methods, so constructing the date that we want is straightforward and trouble-free.

```
public class Booking {

    private LocalDate bookingDate;
    private int ssn;
    
    public Booking(LocalDate bookingDate, int ssn) {
        this.bookingDate = bookingDate;
        this.ssn = ssn;
    }
}
```

Now your main code could be:

```
        bookings.add(new Booking(LocalDate.of(2020, Month.NOVEMBER, 11), ssn));
```

Many will find the code easier to read if we break it up a bit:

```
        LocalDate newBookingDate = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.NOVEMBER, 11);
        Booking newBooking = new Booking(newBookingDate, ssn);
        bookings.add(newBooking);
```

You notice that there are no funny numberings. Year 2020 is 2020, and you may alternatively pass November as the number 11 if you prefer. Isn’t there still the risk of putting the arguments in the wrong order?

```
        LocalDate newBookingDate = LocalDate.of(11, Month.NOVEMBER, 2020);
```

This throws:

> Exception in thread "main" java.time.DateTimeException: Invalid value
> for DayOfMonth (valid values 1 - 28/31): 2020

Read the message. It tells us that we put 2020 where the day of month was expected. Enjoy how much more helpful this is than the behaviour of the deprecated `Date` constructor that you tried to use.

### Aside: a note on naming

Variables in Java begin with a lowercase letter, so prefer `ssn` over `SSN`. Also when in the domain SSN is an abbreviation and always written in upper case.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time.